# How to find the parametric equation of $x^y=y^x$ without Lambert W function?

Tags: exponential-function, parametric

This is sort of a follow-up to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853100/solve-3y-y3-space-y-neq1-space-y-neq3). I've done basic conversions of parametric to to cartesian and back as part of my A-level, but never anything more advanced than a sin/cos relationship.

I want to find a parametric version of this: $\space x^y=y^x$

I've already found the answer on [this site](http://www.geogebratube.org/material/show/id/3940), but it doesn't show a method for getting it.

Would anyone mind giving a little tutorial?

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_August_24#Rational_solutions_of_x.5Ey_.3D_y.5Ex) might prove itself useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One standard way to find a parametrization of $F(x,y)=0$ is to set $y=tx$. In your case it gives the following parametrization of non-trivial branch: $$\Large x=t^{\frac{1}{t-1}},\quad y=t^{\frac{t}{t-1}},$$
for $t>0$, $t\neq 1$.